# Can we use the Chi-Square table for the Sign Test of small sample? What are the different versions of a Sign Test?

Tags: probability, statistics

Following are measurements of breaking strength of a certain kind of two inch cotton ribbon in pounds

> 163 165 160 189 161 171 158 151 169 162 163 139 172 165 148 166 172
>   163 187 173

Use the sign test to test Null Hypothesis $\mu=160$ against alternate Hypothesis $\mu > 160$ at 5% LOS.

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate a sign test using R statistical software. To begin,
we put the data into a vector `x`, count the observations, and then sort them.

```
  x=c(163, 165, 160, 189, 161, 171, 158, 151, 169, 162, 
      163, 139, 172, 165, 148, 166, 172, 163, 187, 173) 
  sx = sort(x);  sx
  ##    139 148 151 158 160 161 162 163 163 163 
  ##    165 165 166 169 171 172 172 173 187 189
  sum(sx > 160)
  ## 15
```

We see that there are 20 observations, of which 15 exceed 160.
In a formal sign test the five observations with values below
160 would be called 'minuses' and those above 'plusses'. (Because one
observation is exactly equal to 160 we thrown it out; it can't
provide any evidence against $\mu = 160.$)

Now think of the random variable $Y \sim Binom(n = 19, p = 1/2)$,
which counts the number of plusses (successes), under the null
hypothesis. We seek the p-value, which is the probability of
a result as or more extreme than what we observed. Specifically,
for the $one$-sided test about which you ask, we need to evaluate
 $$P(Y \ge 15) = 1 - P(Y \le 14) \approx 0.0096.$$ 
In R this is computed as follows:

```
 1 - pbinom(14, 19, .5)
 ## 0.009605408
```

Because the p-value is smaller than 5%, we reject the null
hypothesis at the 5% level of significance.
In R there is a function `binom.test` that does all of this
in one step (where `...` indicates I have
omitted some output that is not directly relevant).

```
 binom.test(15, 19, .5, alte="greater")

         Exact binomial test

 data:  15 and 19 
 number of successes = 15, number of trials = 19, p-value =  0.009605

 ...
```

You could use the normal approximation to find the p-value:
Let $\mu = E(Y) = np = 19(.5) = 9.5$ and $\sigma = SD(Y) =
\sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{4.75}.$ Then $Z = (Y - \mu)/\sigma$ is
approximately standard normal. Thus, the p-value is approximated
as
$$P(Y < 14.5) = P(Z < (14.5 - 9.5)/\sqrt{4.75} =  2.294157
) \approx 0.011,$$
where the numerical result can be obtained from printed normal
tables or from software. (Notice that the normal approximation
is not quite accurate to the second decimal place in this case.)

In the figure below, the vertical bars show the distribution $Binom(19, 1/2)$, the total heights of the heavy bars at the
right is the p-value, and the curve is the density of $Norm(9.5, \sqrt{4.75}).$

[image]

Finally, you asked whether the chi-squared distribution can be
used to solve this problem. Consider the random variable $Z^2 = Q \sim Chisq(df=1)$.
For a $two$-sided test you could use 
$$1 - P(-2.012 < Z < 2.294) = P(Q = Z^2 > 2.294^2 =  5.262)$$ and
use tables of the chi-squared distribution or software to
find that $P(Q >  5.262) \approx 0.0218,$ which is the
approximate p-value for a two-sided test. But this does not
directly solve your problem. So it seems an unnecessary
complication to use the chi-squared distribution here.

$Addendum:$ Perhaps you have already learned about t tests
or will see them soon in your course. A t test takes into
account the exact value of each observation (not just whether
it is above or below 160). Some results for the appropriate one-sample, one-sided t test are shown below:

```
  t.test(x, mu=160, alt="g")

         One Sample t-test

 data:  x 
 t = 1.8735, df = 19, p-value = 0.03823
 alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 160 
 ...
```

A t test requires data to be approximately normal. Even though
your data show a couple of near outliers, a Shapiro-Wilk test
does not reject the null hypothesis of normality.